# fetching data from GraphQL server through apollo environment through its client

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-android

I am storing the data in json format in GraphQL server and making a query like:

```
query {
  symptoms{
    id
    name
    picUrl
  }
}
```

Now I have to fetch it from the server using its client.
My app gradle.build file is as follows:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.apollographql.android:api:0.1.0' 
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0' // retrofit2
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0' 
    compile 'com.apollographql.android:converter-pojo:0.1.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and in module gradle.build I have:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.3'
        classpath 'com.apollographql.android:gradle-plugin:0.1.0'
}
```

Now in the Adapter class I need to write the code to fetch the data.
I am following this link https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android
But I am getting error while writing this code itself:

```
ApolloClient apolloClient;
apolloClient.newCall(FeedQuery.builder()
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It is not detecting newCall function after apolloClient variable.

Comment: Why are you using 0.1.0 [instead of 0.3.3](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android)?

Comment: you want me to use 0.3.3 for android:gradle-plugin:0.1.0'?

Comment: Read [the documentation for the current builds of Apollo-Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) and follow their instructions. They do not use the dependencies that you are using. For example, they no longer use the `com.apollographql.android` group.